# Determining if a file exists in C based on the string path

Tags: c

I have a C string that I want to use to open that file. How do I determine if the file exists?

Comment: Have you tried checking if fopen returns a non-null file descriptor?

Comment: Have you googled or tried anything?

Comment: If the end goal is to *open* the file, then the easiest thing to do is to try and open it, and see if it fails. But there are cases where you can see if the file exists (no matter if you're allowed to open it), in which case you want to use the below-mentioned `access()` or `stat()` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function called access()

```
if(access(file_path, F_OK)==0)
    //file exists
else
    // file does not exists
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's answers are valid (with minor tweeks) here but make some assumptions. First, if it actually a file your checking or is it possibly a file/directory/symlink/fifo/socket/etc. If it's just a file, the fopen(), stat() and access() solutions won't work.

fopen() will succeed on nearly all object types in many operating systems (including a valid directory), while stat() and access() will most certainly success regardless of filesystem object type in all operating systems (they will always succeed is a filesystem object exists and is accessable in the current security context [logged in user]). Even worse, windows compilers will treat stat differently (because they either link to msvc's lib or they inline their own implemenation).

Sadly, your best approach (if determining if a **file** exists and you want to be portable) is something like...

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
#else
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif

int file_exists(const char* filename) {
    #ifdef _WIN32
        HANDLE h = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
        if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return 0;
        int res = 0;
        if (GetFileType(h) == FILE_TYPE_DISK)
            res = 1;
        CloseHandle(h);
        return res;
    #else
        struct stat st;
        if (stat(filename, &st) == -1)
            return 0;
        return S_ISREG(st.st_mode);
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it is easiest to just open the file for writing. If there is a problem you will get a NULL file handle back.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fileExists(const char* path) {
    FILE* f = fopen(path, "rb");
    if (!f) {
        return 0;
    }
    fclose(path);
    return 1;
}
```

Of course, if you are going to want to read from the file, you shouldn't fclose() the handle immediately.

Comment: There is no reason to open the file for writing to test if a file exists.

Comment: This doesn't determine whether the file exists or not. A file can exist without needing read/write access to it.

Comment: You *could* check `errno` and see whether it is set to `ENOENT`

Comment: This is a pretty acceptable solution imho; the end goal is to see if a file exists in order to open it (stated in the question). Also, it opens the file for reading, not for writing. So I think this works!

Comment: @poundifdef: This isn't an acceptable solution, because the name of the function is misleading. If it was called "fileCanBeOpenedForReading" then this function may be suitable. If the OP wants to open the file anyway, there is no point in determining whether it exists first because any of the `open`/`fopen`/`fdopen` will fail if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `stat`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   struct stat s;

   if (stat("/path/to/file", &s) == -1) {
      printf("Invalid path\n");
   } else {
      printf("Valid path\n");
   }   

   return 0;

}
```

This does not tell you whether your program has permissions to read or write the file (`fopen()` is good for that) but this will tell you whether or not the path exists.